# How can the significand width in bits of float, double be determined: Is there a standard definition?

Tags: c++, c, linux, floating-point, ieee-754

Is there a standard manner to determine the width of the significand of a double, in C or C++?  I am aware that IEEE-754 format of a double stores the significand in 53 bits, but I would like to avoid using a “magic” number in my code.

On Linux, the file `usr/include/ieee754.h` exists, but it describes the format using bit fields in a structure, which I cannot determine the size of (at compile time).

A Linux-only solution is acceptable.

Comment: Based on *"... mantissa in 53 bits ..."* and *"... determine the size (at compile time)"*, I believe OP is seeking a define or constant for the size of the mantissa in bits.

Comment: @jww Yes, I _am_ looking for a define or constance for the size of the signifcand (mantissa) in bits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `FLT_MANT_DIG` and `DBL_MANT_DIG`, defined in `<float.h>`:

```
#include <float.h>
#include <stdio.h>


#if FLT_RADIX != 2
    #error "Floating-point base is not two."
#endif


int main(void)
{
    printf("There are %d bits in the significand of a float.\n",
        FLT_MANT_DIG);
    printf("There are %d bits in the significand of a double.\n",
        DBL_MANT_DIG);
}
```

Comment: But note that knowing how many bits does not tell you which ones they are.  Also, the OP may need to account for the leading 1 bit that is implicit in normalized IEEE-754 representations.

Comment: [link to GNU documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Floating-Point-Parameters.html)

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a standard manner to determine the mantissa of a double?

You're willing to accept a Linux-specific solution, but you claim that glibc's `ieee754.h` header does not satisfy your needs, so I conclude that the problem you are trying to solve is not extracting or conveying the bits themselves, as that header's `union ieee_double` would provide a means for you to do that.

I read "the mantissa" as a different thing from "the number of bits of mantissa", so I conclude that `DBL_MANT_DIG` of `float.h` is not what you're looking for, either.

The only other thing I can think of that you might mean is the *value* of the significand (mantissa), according to the standard floating point model:

*v* = (*sign*) * *significand* * *radix*<sup>*exponent*</sup>

The [`frexp()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/frexp) function, in the C language standard since C99, serves this purpose.<sup>1</sup>  It separates a `double` into an exponent (of 2) and a significand, represented as a `double`.  For a finite, nonzero input, the absolute value of the result is in the half-open interval [0.5, 1).

**Example**:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void print_parts(double d) {
    int exp;
    double significand = frexp(d, &exp);

    printf("%e = %f * 2^%d\n", d, significand, exp);
}
```

***Sample outputs***:

> 7.256300e+16 = 0.503507 * 2^57
>   1.200000e-03 = 0.614400 * 2^-9
>   -0.000000e+00 = -0.000000 * 2^0

Note that although the example function does not print sufficient decimal digits to convey the significands exactly, `frexp()` itself is exact, not subject to any rounding errors.

---

<sup>1</sup> Technically, `frexp()` serves the purpose *provided that* `FLT_RADIX` expands to 2.  It is well-defined in any case, but if your `double` representation uses a different radix then the result of `frexp()`, though well-defined, is probably not what you're looking for.

Comment: I apologise that you were forced to determine what I was asking for: I don't want to have to assume that the bit width of the mantissa is 53 bits.  I'd rather have a macro that tells my code: "_the bit width of the mantissa for a double is DBL_MANT_BIT_WIDTH_" (say).

Comment: Well that would be the `DBL_MANT_DIG` macro from `float.h` that both answers reference.  Do choose Eric's answer over mine, though, as he was first, guessed correctly what you wanted, and even provided a nice example demonstrating it.

Answer (score 2):

In C++ you might use `std::numeric_limits<double>::digits` and `std::numeric_limits<float>::digits`:

```
#include <limits>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::numeric_limits<float>::digits << "\n";
    std::cout << std::numeric_limits<double>::digits << "\n";
}
```

prints

```
24
53
```

respectively.