# How float and double numbers are represented in ANSI C?

Tags: c, floating-point, ieee-754, ansi-c

I would like to understand how floating-point values (`float` and `double`) are represented in ANSI C. That is, how many bits are used for representing the mantissa and the exponent of `float` and `double` values?

I'm not sure if ANSI C adopts IEEE 754.

Comment: note that most mainstream platforms (e.g.  x86-64, AARCH64) are IEEE 754 compatible, on these platforms `float` is a  binary32 (i.e. 32bit in single-precision floating point format) while a `double` is a binary64 (i.e. 64bit double-precision).  note that optional optimization levels (e.g. `-ffast-math` in GCC/Clang) can break compatibility, even though the bit-level representation is the same

Answer (score 0):

C doesn't mandate any specific floating-point format. It doesn't even say that floating-point types must be in binary, so it's valid for an implementation to use decimal floats. In fact there are many old floating-point formats that use hexadecimal instead of binary

Just like integer types, C just specifies various limits of floating-point types like the radix or the number of digits in the significand and exponent parts like

- FLT_RADIX
- FLT_MANT_DIG, DBL_MANT_DIG, LDBL_MANT_DIG
- FLT_MIN_EXP, DBL_MIN_EXP, LDBL_MIN_EXP
- FLT_MAX_EXP, DBL_MAX_EXP, LDBL_MAX_EXP
- ...

So you can use them if you just want to know *how many bits are used for representing the mantissa and the exponent of float and double values*

For more details read C11's [5.2.4.2.2 Characteristics of floating types `<float.h>`](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.2.4.2.2)

If you want to make sure that the implementation uses IEEE-754 then you can check it with `__STDC_IEC_559__`

See also

- [How can the significand width in bits of float, double be determined: Is there a standard definition?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56872769/995714)
- [Is it safe to assume floating point is represented using IEEE754 floats in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31967040/995714)